# How to stop the current Index creation Operation in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I am try to add an index in DynamoDB table having size around 200MB.

its took almost 15 hours and is still running. 
I have checked that i have given the low read/write IOPS for index.
Now i want to increase IOPS and restart the index creation activity.

Any idea - If its possible to cancel the current operation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html

> You cannot cancel an in-flight global secondary index creation.

But on the plus side you are incorrect that you need to cancel the operation to change the throughput capacity.

> If the provisioned write throughput setting on the index is too low,
>   the index build will take longer to complete. To shorten the time it
>   takes to build a new global secondary index, you can increase its
>   provisioned write capacity temporarily.

EDIT:

> After the index has been created, you should set its provisioned write
>   capacity to reflect the normal usage of your application.

Comment: is the temporarily increased capacity works at runtime ?

Comment: See edit. You increase index capacity during creation, the index build runs faster, afterward you change the capacity again to match your operational use.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the read capacity units and write capacity units values of a currently running index creation using the AWS CLI:

Create a file named gsi-update-MyIndex.json with the following content:

```
[
  {
    "Update": {
      "IndexName": "BluekaiID-index",
      "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 100
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Then, execute the following command:

> aws dynamodb update-table --table-name mytablename --global-secondary-index-updates file://gsi-update-MyIndex.json

You'll probably want to bump up the values on the main table for a minute, too with the following command:

> aws dynamodb update-table --table-name mytablename --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=100,WriteCapacityUnits=1

Once your index creation is done and loaded, rerun the commands above with smaller values to fit your normal traffic.

Comment: You can do this in the console too.